# Using sincerity to describe openness

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is the following a proper sentence?

> His sincerity concerning intimate issues made the old man increasingly uncomfortable

I am not sure about using 'concerning' with sincerity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your question more concerns the use of 'sincerity' or the use of 'concerning', or proper sentence structure. However, per the title of the question, I would say that sincerity is not the best word to describe openness in this context.

Sincerity indicates honesty and straightforwardness, but does not necessarily imply that one will offer the truth without being asked. I believe you may be looking for the word **candor**. 
Per [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candor)'s definition #4:

> unreserved, honest, or sincere expression :  forthrightness

Specifically, candor's connotation of forthrightness seems to better fit your example sentence. A merely sincere person may not necessarily be forthright enough to bring up a topic that makes others uncomfortable.

Comment: I agree with you. Another usable alternative is "frankness."

Comment: I did not know the term 'candor'. It seems to be most suitable to express what I mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a proper sentence. Concerning, regarding, etc. would be fine in that sentence.  Concerning is properly used as a preposition in the noun/prepositional phrase form:

noun + prepositional phrase

http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/nounphrase.htm